# CSS class Disabled?

Tags: css, class, html, firebug, border

For my vBulletin forum, avatar images are pulled with this:

```
<img src="{vb:raw post.avatarurl}" alt="{vb:rawphrase xs_avatar, {vb:raw post.username}}" title="{vb:rawphrase xs_avatar, {vb:raw post.username}}" class="forumavatar1" />
```

Note the class="forumavatar1"

The css for this class as is follows:

```
.forumavatar1 {
padding: 2px;
border: 1px solid black;
background: white;
}
```

But for some reason the black border is not showing. On Google Chrome and Firebug, this border: element is being crossed out ??

Example page, look at someone's avatar image: http://forums.animefushigi.com/showthread.php?31-So-about-that-dark-theme

Comment: What do the developer tools tell you it's being overridden by?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try reading this article on [CSS Specificity](http://css-tricks.com/855-specifics-on-css-specificity/) - in short, your single-class selector is being overridden by a multi-class selector. To fix this (although I wouldn't recommend this as a permanent fix), you can change your style above to:

```
.forumavatar1 {
    padding: 2px;
    border: 1px solid black !important;
    background: white;
}
```

I would suggest instead, that you take a look at and modify the style which is overriding it, which is:

```
.postbitlegacy .userinfo .postuseravatar img, .eventbit .userinfo .eventuseravatar img {
    border: 0 solid #F2F6F8;
    max-width: 180px;
    outline: 0 dotted #DADADA;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll stick with using the !important for now

Comment: Alright. Like I said, it's not a very useful fix, only because it interrupts the idea of CSS being _Cascading_ Style Sheets, but unless you plan on doing much more editing to that specific style target, that will function fine.

Answer (score 2):

this happens because `.postbitlegacy .userinfo .postuseravatar img, .eventbit .userinfo .eventuseravatar img`  have `border: 0 solid #F2F6F8;` and this override the selector `.forumavatar1`. You can change the [selector's specificity](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#specificity) from `.forumavatar1` to `.userinfo .postuseravatar img.forumavatar1` this will make it black.

Additional article for specificity: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/

Even if it's very helpful method, use it wisely.

As last refuge I suggest [`!important`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#important-rules)

Answer (score 1):

If it's crossed out then something else with higher priority is overriding it. Try adding an !important to it to see if that will make it work.

```
border: 1px solid black !important;
```

If it does, you can either keep the !important or find out what is overriding it.